# Django Rest Framework - updating a field in django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am new to django and trying to update some data in my model using by using the PUT methed in the *views.py*. Here is what I've done.

```
@api_view(['PUT'])

def check_coupon(request):

    global kid_id, code, serializer
    try:

        code = request.POST['code']
        kid_id = request.POST['kid_id']

    except KeyError:
        x = None

    if request.method == 'PUT':

        if services.check_coupon(code) == 1:
            services.update_coupon(code, kid_id) # this updates the data 

            serializer = serializers.CouponSerializer(data=request.data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

update coupon:

```
def update_coupon(code, kid_id):
    kid = KidUser.objects.get(id=kid_id)
    Coupon.objects.filter(code=code).update(kid_id=kid,used=True)
    KidUser.objects.filter(id=kid_id).update(user_type='P')
```

This creates a new coupon object instead of updating the existing one. How can I update a specific field.My input field in the body are the user id and the code.

Comment: remove `serializer.save()` . `.save()` will create new instance with validated data

Comment: While it does get updated in the database. The response still does not show the fields updated fields.

Comment: How do you get your coupon instance ?

Comment: I dont, I directly update the coupon with the specific coupon code using update method in the services.py file i have created.

Comment: After successful operation what data you wish to display ?

Comment: Can you please add the services.update_coupon() code snippet?

Comment: I would like to see the updated data of that snippet. @JerinPeterGeorge.

Comment: @SaranshAgarwal I updated the answer